# How can I get the jquery gzoom plugin working?

Tags: jquery

I have picked up a jquery plugin called gzoom from [the gzoom site](http://lab.gianiaz.com/jquery/gzoom/) as it seems to be able to do what I want (variable zoom). I have also seen this [previous question  on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19659646/jquery-gzoom-plugin-doesnt-work)  that seems to have been resolved.  I am not very familiar with js and jquery, and am probably missing something easy.

I have downloaded a custom version of the latest jquery-ui (with jquery) - version 1.11.2 - into my PDC folder. I have also downloaded the two gzoom files - jquery.gzoom.css and jquery.gzoom.js. I am testing on a WAMP, outside the WordPress environment for now.

My html file (adapted from the above sources) is

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>test gzoom</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/PDC/jquery-ui-1.11.2.custom/jquery-ui.min.css">
<script src="/PDC/jquery-ui-1.11.2.custom/external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/PDC/jquery-ui-1.11.2.custom/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/PDC/gzoom/css/jquery.gzoom.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/PDC/gzoom/jquery/jquery.gzoom.js"></script>
<style>
    div#zoom{
        cursor: crosshair;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="gzoomwrap">
    <div id="zoom" class="zoom minizoompan">
         <img src='/wp/wp-content/uploads/HcN-sign-for-palette.jpg'/>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  /*<![CDATA[*/
  $(function() {
    $zoom = $("#zoom").gzoom({
        sW: 300,
        sH: 225,
        lW: 1400,
        lH: 1050,
        lightbox : false
    });
  });
  /*]]>*/
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The image and slider display OK, but when I move the slider the image does not change. The only error I can see (using Chrome) is

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined jquery.gzoom.js:94
>   and this line is `var hiSrc = ig.attr("src").replace(settings.re, settings.replace);`

I have tried one or two different jquery versions but they have all had the same problem. What have I done wrong?
Thanks

Comment: The next morning... I find it now works! I don't know what I have changed. The only remaining problem seems to be that there is a little box in the top left saying "loading...". Can anyone help with that?